# JavaScript prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Below is a simple JavaScript inheritance example. Can we replace the line: Dog.prototype = new Animal();
with Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype?

I have tested in the browser, and they are giving me the same result. It's strange to me that why we need to create a new Animal object and assign it to Dog.prototype.

```
function Animal(age){
    this.age = age;
}

Animal.prototype.walk = function(){
     console.log("Walk"); 
}

function Dog(color, age){
    this.color = color;
    Animal.call(this, age)
}

Dog.prototype = new Animal();      //Why not Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;


dog_b = new Dog("yellow", 9);
console.log("Age: " + dog_b.age +  " Color: " + dog_b.color );
dog_b.walk()
```

Comment: "*It's strange to me that why we need to create a new Animal object*" - good intuition. You [should not use `new Animal` there indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you can replace the lines for a simple reason:

```
function Dog(color, age) {
    this.color = color;
    Animal.call(this, age); // This line
}
```

Here, you're calling Animal's constructor with `call` providing it `this` thus establishing Animal's context manually. And so `this` inside `function Animal` will always refer to the `Dog`'s object. That's why a `new` won't make a difference at all.

Strictly speaking, you're not actually doing proper prototypal inheritance. You can confirm that by doing:

```
dog_b.hasOwnProperty('age'); // => true
```

This is actually called `constructor stealing` where `Dog` stealing `Animal`'s constructor. The `walk` method though is on `Animal`'s ctor.

Which means the `age` property is on `Dog` itself and not on `Animal`. Why is that? Again, because you're establishing `Animal`'s constructor context manually to be that of the `Dog`.

**Edit:**

In Javascript there are various ways of describing and attaining inheritance, and since this is not a place for writing a book I'll be quick.

What you're doing is called `Parasitic Combination Inheritance` (you don't have to remember the term). It's not wrong, it's simply another way of obtaining inheritance (which is prototypal only for functions that are on `Animal.prototype`). If it's working for you I'd say take it. If you really really want `Animal`'s `age` to be on `Animal`, then you'll face problems when using constructors to obtain inheritance.

One way of doing this would be:

```
function inherit(o){
    function F(){}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}

var foo = {
    name: 'some'
}

var bar = inherit(foo); // bar.name refers to the object on foo
```

As you can see, prototypal inheritance is usually used for object literals (think angular's scope object).

Comment: So what is the right way to write the Dog() constructor without constructor stealing?

Comment: I'm not sure about your first line. Are you suggesting that both `Dog.prototype = new Animal();` and `Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype` are fine? Or even, that they do the same thing?

Comment: I've never heard the term "constructor stealing". Given that `Dog` is supposed to inherit from `Animal`, it just would be a *[super](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses) call*.

Comment: @Bergi I'm simply saying that the end result of replacing that line would be the same (almost). And I don't think the term is common but it's written in a couple of books I've read. OP check the edit.